# Latest API version in APex class

Tags: apex, httprequest, httpresponse

I have tried to get latest api version through /service/data . I have refered this link also *[Find current API version in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116645/find-current-api-version-in-apex/116651)*

But when i used latest version in this :

```
final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/+version+/query');
theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select Name From ApexClass');
```

Its throwing 404 error response. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you get the API version using rest API, you need to provide proper base URL. I think when you run get base URL from VF page it adds `c.` or a `{namespace}.` in URL depending if org has a namespace. Try hardcoding the URL to check if its issue with URL:?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a couple of quotation marks, so you're trying to call the literal url:

```
/services/data/+version+/query
```

Instead of what you intended:

```
/services/data/40.0/query
```

You need to add the missing quotes:

```
final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/'+version+'/query');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the API version like this as well:

```
ApexClass classObj = [SELECT ApiVersion FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'YourClassName'];
System.debug(classObj.ApiVersion);
```

Comment: ..Thanks for the reply ...But it will give me  APex class api version.it is giving me apex class api version only.